# How Do I join these 2 SQL queries into one single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have 2 queries that I run separately and I now need to join these queries so that I have a single output.

Query 1 stand as follows:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
   c.Createdon,
   a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
   b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
   b.ReservationStatus AS 'Status',
   d.rsl_rateplan AS 'Rate Plan Code',
   d.rsl_mealplan,
   d.rsl_roomtype,
   b.MarketSegmentCode AS 'Market Segment', 
   e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business',
   a.ArrivalDate AS 'Date of Arrival',
   a.DepartureDate AS 'Date of Departure',
   (SELECT DATEDIFF (day,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate) 
    FROM ReservationStay c
    WHERE c.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Nights',
   c.AdultCount AS 'Adult',
   c.ChildCount AS 'Child',
   b.GuestCount AS 'Guest',
   d.rsl_reasonstay,
   c.TaProfileID,
   c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
   c.CurrencyCode As 'Currency',
   d.rsl_nationality AS 'Nationality',
   d.rsl_country AS 'Country of Residence',
   d.rsl_totalroomrate,
   e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
   e.CountryCode AS 'Market Code',     
   g.CountryGroup AS 'Market',


 (SELECT avg(RateAmount)/1.15
  FROM ReservationStayDate f
  where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT',

  c.TAProfileID2,
  e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)',
  g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)'




 FROM GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
 LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
 LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode


WHERE a.PrimaryGuest='+' and d.rsl_primaryguest='+'

ORDER by a.ReservationStayID
```

And the second query is:

```
use MyDatabase

select *

FROM (SELECT 
  ReservationStayID,count(reservationstayid) AS [Nights Spent],
  datename(m,StayDate)+' '+ cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
  avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
  CreatedOn

from ReservationStayDate

GROUP BY ReservationStayID,STAYDATE,RATEAMOUNT,CreatedOn

) AS S

ORDER by ReservationstayID
```

Should that be an INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN or a completely different syntax?

Additional info:

Ok, to be more explicit, here are a few pointers. The ReservationStayDate table list the guest stay by date of stay (StayDate). So, if a guest stays between 2014-10-31 to 2014-11-04, the ReservationStayDate table will show 4 rows for each night spent (ie: 2014-10-31,2014-11-01,2014-11-02 and 2014-11-03).

When I run the first query, my output is one row for each guest. Now I need my output for guests who spend nights over 2 months (like the example above) to appear on 2 rows, with the added column name 'MTH' (which is fact shows month and year) and "Nights Spent". So, output will look like this for a guest who spends all nights in the same month and for those who overlap over 2 months:

```
ReservationStayId     CreatedOn........ DateOfArrival  DateOfDeparture  MTH      Nights
     250                                 2014-09-05    2014-09-07    Sept 2014    2
     285                                 2014-10-31    2014-11-04    Oct 2014     1
     285                                 2014-10-31    2014-11-04    Nov 2014     3
```

I hope I've made it a little clearer to understand. If not, please comment and I'll add more specific info.

Comment: Table structures? Expected result? etc... As more specific you are in your question, you get more chance to get proper help.

Comment: Create SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: First of all: Your second query doesn't make sense. You group by reservationstayid. So `count(reservationstayid)` is always 1, not the "nights spent". Moreover reservationstayid is probably the table's key. So `avg(RateAmount)` is the avarage over one record always, hence avg(RateAmount) = RateAmount. Your first query is broken concerning your outer joins. You outer join `P5RESERVATIONLIST d`, but then you have `d.rsl_primaryguest='+'` in your where clause, thus removing any outer-joined record (because its rsl_primaryguest will be null).

Comment: When u combine, 2 results, tell whether you want it to be just appended (UNION, EXCEPT etc..), or Joined so that more columns from both will be added as result (JOINS)...Please make your question more specific.

Comment: Question edited with additional info.

Comment: My last comment was not quite correct. Here it is corrected: Your second query doesn't make sense. You group by reservationstayid and staydate which make presumably the table's natural unique key. So count(reservationstayid) is always 1, not the "nights spent". Equally, avg(RateAmount) is the avarage over one record always, hence avg(RateAmount) = RateAmount. Your first query is broken concerning your outer joins. You outer join P5RESERVATIONLIST d, but then you have d.rsl_primaryguest='+' in your where clause, thus removing any outer-joined record (because its rsl_primaryguest will be null).

Comment: I've given you a corrected second query in my answer that should meet your request. You can run it alone, to see its results and check if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a derived table. That is a query that you join just like you would join a table.

```
SELECT 
  ...
  x.[Nights Spent],
  x.[MTH],
  x.[Rate],
  x.CreatedOn,
  x.[DateOfArrival],
  x.[DateOfDeparture]
FROM GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH]
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
   FROM ReservationStayDate
   GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 ...
```

<strike>As already mentioned in the comments to your request, your second query as is makes no sense</strike> EDIT: I've changed the second query according to your edited request.

As mentioned, the first query is broken regarding outer joins. One more advice: Use readable alias names, not a, b, c, but maybe gni for GuestNameInfo, gss for GuestStaySummary and the like. Just so that you don't have to look up the from/join clauses whenever you want to know what table a column belongs to.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer, so the derived table query should now do what you want it to do. WAIT. I'll have to make another change...

Comment: Done. I had to add DateOfArrival and DateOfDeparture which you also want to see in your results.

Answer (score -1):

Try This Hope it Will Work....

```
select 
 a.ReservationStayID,
c.Createdon,
a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
b.ReservationStatus AS 'Status',
d.rsl_rateplan AS 'Rate Plan Code',
d.rsl_mealplan,
d.rsl_roomtype,
b.MarketSegmentCode AS 'Market Segment', 
e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business',
a.ArrivalDate AS 'Date of Arrival',
a.DepartureDate AS 'Date of Departure',
(SELECT DATEDIFF (day,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate) 
FROM ReservationStay c
WHERE c.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Nights',
c.AdultCount AS 'Adult',
c.ChildCount AS 'Child',
b.GuestCount AS 'Guest',
d.rsl_reasonstay,
c.TaProfileID,
c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
c.CurrencyCode As 'Currency',
d.rsl_nationality AS 'Nationality',
d.rsl_country AS 'Country of Residence',
d.rsl_totalroomrate,
e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
e.CountryCode AS 'Market Code',     
g.CountryGroup AS 'Market',-------change to g.CountryName to obtain Original Markets
c.TAProfileID2,
e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)',
g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)'

,s.*,

(SELECT avg(RateAmount)/1.15
FROM ReservationStayDate f
where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT'




 from  GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
  LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
  LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode
 inner join 
  (SELECT 
   ReservationStayID,count(reservationstayid) AS [Nights Spent],
  Convert(varchar,datename(m,StayDate)+' '+ cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) ) as [MTH],
   avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
   CreatedOn

 from ReservationStayDate

 GROUP BY ReservationStayID,STAYDATE,RATEAMOUNT,CreatedOn

 ) AS S on s.ReservationStayID=a.ReservationStayID

 WHERE a.PrimaryGuest='+' and d.rsl_primaryguest='+'
 and  f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT',

 ORDER by ReservationstayID
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this message:
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 63
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: Remove comma(,)  after "AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT'" Statement

Comment: Dhaval, I still get an error:

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 66
Incorrect syntax near ')'"